# Past perfect with know

Tags: past-perfect

I knew I was german

I knew I had been german

Can someone explain the difference between these to and when to use them?

Comment: _German_ should have a capital G, but it's an odd adjective to choose as an example. "I knew I was ill" (at the time I'm talking about). "I knew I had been ill" (previous to that time).

Comment: I knew I had been German before it occured I was Polish.  I knew I was German all my life. Correct?

Comment: Changing nationality isn't something that happens unconsciously! You could say "I had thought I was German until I discovered that I was actually Polish."

Comment: 1 I realized I met her vs 2 I realized I had met her. Can you explain the difference here? Please

Comment: The first one makes no sense. If you met someone at a moment in the past, you saw her there in front of you; you didn't 'realise' that it was happening.

Answer (score 0):

"I knew I was ill"

You are talking about a time in the past.  At that time you had knowledge that at that time you were ill

"I knew I had been ill"

You are talking about a time in the past. At that time you had knowledge that at a time prior to that time you were ill.

I've changed it from "German" to "ill" because the sentence is completely incongruous when used with "German". It makes no sense at all.

Comment: Could you provide some sentences?

Comment: I already provided two...